# Bring up ContextMenu when IsMouseOver on a Button using only XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu, ismouseover

I am trying to use XAML (only, no codebehind) to bring up the ContextMenu of a button.

I have this my button here

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Style="{StaticResource mybutton}" >
<Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <TextBlock Text="Information"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

The Style for the button here

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="mybutton">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu.IsOpen" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

My google-fu is failing me for what seems like an easy solution.  I really would prefer to avoid using codebehind (MouseEnter/MouseLeave events).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to apply "Setter" for a ContextMenu within the ControlTemplate, by providing it's name in the "TargetName" property. For example:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100" x:Name="btn">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="DarkGray" x:Name="border">
                                <Border.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu x:Name="cmenu">
                                        <TextBlock>Information</TextBlock>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </Border.ContextMenu>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu.IsOpen" Value="True" TargetName="cmenu"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... This gets me partially to where I want to be.  The issue with this solution is that I can't select anything within the ContextMenu since it redraws as the mouse moves.  IsMouseOver may not be the right solution for me but this gets me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want i guess -
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/adafe007-9637-4f28-8366-8f14ead2bd75

```
All you need to do is capture the mouse event that you want to trigger the context menu.
```

Comment: I saw this before.  I am looking for a way to do it without any codebehind, thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use a mouse_up event in codebehind. With `MouseOver` the user feels fooled as the context menu is gone when the mouse moves towards an entry...
In VB the code looks like:

```
Private Sub image_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles image.MouseUp
    anyControl.ContextMenu.IsOpen = Not OrteListBox.ContextMenu.IsOpen
End Sub
```

`anyCountrol` stands for the sender or any other control that holds the `ContextMenu`