# MenuShowDelay - also for keyboard?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, contextmenu

I'm creating a context and I'm trying to have the submenus for items auto appear like they do when you hover over with the mouse.

Am I missing a setting to make this happen?
If not any suggestions how to make it work please?

Thanks.

Edit - Hmm, maybe I'm not clear - currently the mouse hover functions correctly - submenus of the main context menu open when I hover over them with the mouse. I'm trying to achieve a similar thing when a menu item gets focus from the keyboard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774744/bring-up-contextmenu-when-ismouseover-on-a-button-using-only-xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle `GotKeyboardFocus` and set `IsSubmenuOpen` to `true`. Here is an example, you can make a behavior based on it.

```
<TextBox Text="test">
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="111"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="222"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="333" GotKeyboardFocus="MenuItem_GotKeyboardFocus">
                <MenuItem Header="fff" />
                <MenuItem Header="ggg" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="444"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>

    private void MenuItem_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
if ((sender as MenuItem) != null)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { (sender as MenuItem).IsSubmenuOpen = true; }), null);
            }
    }
```

Comment: why do you need to do it with BeginInvoke?

Comment: Without I had an issue by arrow left and escape in submenu.